# Using catchfile and envlab packages

Tags: letters, envlab

The following code works well enough:

envelopea.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope,customenvelopes]{envlab}

\SetEnvelope[2.0in]{240mm}{145mm}
\setlength{\EnvelopeTopMargin}{0.75in} % 0.5
\setlength{\EnvelopeLeftMargin}{1.25in} % 2.0

\begin{document}
\startlabels
\mlabel{%
1234 Center Lane \\
Long Mile Village \\
92319%
}%
{%
239 Mill Lake Rd \\
Centreville \\
78392%
}%
\end{document}
```

I would, however, like to use the catchfile package in order to retrieve the addresses from an external file.  An implementation might look something like this.

addressa.tex

```
1234 Center Lane \\%
Long Mile Village \\%
92319%
```

addressb.tex

```
239 Mill Lake Rd \\%
Centreville \\%
78392%
```

letterb.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope,customenvelopes]{envlab}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\getfromaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\gettoaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thetoaddress}{#1}{}}
\providecommand{\expandonce}{\unexpanded\expandafter}

\getfromaddress{addressa.tex}
\gettoaddress{addressb.tex}

\SetEnvelope[2.0in]{240mm}{145mm}
\setlength{\EnvelopeTopMargin}{0.75in} % 0.5
\setlength{\EnvelopeLeftMargin}{1.25in} % 2.0

\begin{document}
\startlabels
\mlabel{%
\expandonce{\thefromaddress}%
}%
{%
\expandonce{\thetoaddress}%
}%
\end{document}
```

When I compile this code I receive an error message which complains of unbalanced curly brackets.  At first glance, things appear to be balanced.  I'm not too familiar with the use of `\expandafter` and `\expandonce`.  I figure that someone might be able to make this work quite easily.  Any comments/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image: Output from the working example]

I have incorporated code presented in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171018/specifying-a-letter-class-address-from-an-external-file-using-catchfile-package) together with code suggested by egreg in order to yield a .cls file for letters which can be called by specifying the following info:

1. File in which from address resides
2. File in which to address resides
3. Letter opening/salutation
4. Letter closing
5. Letter post script
6. Letter signature
7. Envelope dimensions

I have included the code below:

theletter.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{theletterb}[]
\LoadClass[]{letter}
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{catchfile}
\RequirePackage[businessenvelope,customenvelopes]{envlab}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage[textwidth=345.0pt,%
top=2in,
headheight=1.0in,
headsep=0.20in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\getfromaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\gettoaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thetoaddress}{#1}{}}
\providecommand{\expandonce}{\unexpanded\expandafter}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MLABEL}{ }
 {
  \johnchris_mlabel:oo { \thefromaddress } { \thetoaddress }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \johnchris_mlabel:nn \mlabel
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \johnchris_mlabel:nn { oo }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\AtBeginDocument{%
\pagestyle{empty}
\let\ps@firstpage\ps@plain
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\begin{letter}{\expandonce{\thetoaddress}}
      {\expandonce{\thefromaddress}}}\x
  \opening{\theopening}
}%
\AtEndDocument{%
\closing{\theclosing}
\ps{\thepostscript}
\newpage
\startlabels
\MLABEL
\end{letter}
}
```

letter.tex

```
\documentclass{theletter}
\getfromaddress{addressa.tex}
\gettoaddress{addressb.tex}
\newcommand{\theopening}{Dear Recipient}
\newcommand{\theclosing}{Sincerely,}
\newcommand{\thepostscript}{}
\signature{Mae L. Mann}
\SetEnvelope[2.0in]{240mm}{145mm}
\setlength{\EnvelopeTopMargin}{0.75in}
\setlength{\EnvelopeLeftMargin}{1.25in}
\begin{document}
\input{body.tex}
\end{document}
```

And again, the supporting files are:

addressa.tex

```
1234 Center Lane \\%
Long Mile Village \\%
92319%
```

addressb.tex

```
239 Mill Lake Rd \\%
Centreville \\%
78392%
```

body.tex

```
lipsum[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is similar to the one in the other question: `\mlabel` needs to see the explicit delimiters `\\` for working correctly. So you need to expand `\thefromaddress` and `\thetoaddress` before `\mlabel` starts its job.

There are some techniques to cope with this; however, since you're using just one pair of from and to addresses, you just need a parameterless command.

You can choose between

```
\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mlabel
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
    {\expandafter\thefromaddress\expandafter}\expandafter{\thetoaddress}
}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\mlabel{\expandonce{\thefromaddress}}
                    {\expandonce{\thetoaddress}}%
  }\x
}
```

or even

```
\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
  \expandafter\mlabel\expandafter
   {\csname thefromaddress\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter}%
   \expandafter{\thetoaddress}%
}
```

All three definitions will eventually do the same. Choose the most appealing. `;-)`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope,customenvelopes]{envlab}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\newcommand{\getfromaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\gettoaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thetoaddress}{#1}{}}
\providecommand{\expandonce}{\unexpanded\expandafter}

% Definition 1
%\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
%  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\mlabel
%  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
%    {\expandafter\thefromaddress\expandafter}\expandafter{\thetoaddress}
%}

% Definition 2
%\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
%  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
%    \noexpand\mlabel{\expandonce{\thefromaddress}}
%                    {\expandonce{\thetoaddress}}%
%  }\x
%}

% Definition 3
\newcommand{\MLABEL}{%
  \expandafter\mlabel\expandafter
   {\csname thefromaddress\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter}%
   \expandafter{\thetoaddress}%
} 


\getfromaddress{addressa.tex}
\gettoaddress{addressb.tex}

\SetEnvelope[2.0in]{240mm}{145mm}
\setlength{\EnvelopeTopMargin}{0.75in} % 0.5
\setlength{\EnvelopeLeftMargin}{1.25in} % 2.0

\begin{document}
\startlabels
\MLABEL
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more concise version uses `expl3`, the programming layer of LaTeX3. You might appreciate the conciseness: I copy the meaning of `\mlabel` into an internal function with two arguments and then generate a variant that expands the contents of the arguments before taking the normal action.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage[businessenvelope,customenvelopes]{envlab}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\getfromaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thefromaddress}{#1}{}}
\newcommand{\gettoaddress}[1]{\CatchFileDef{\thetoaddress}{#1}{}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\MLABEL}{ }
 {
  \johnchris_mlabel:oo { \thefromaddress } { \thetoaddress }
 }

\cs_set_eq:NN \johnchris_mlabel:nn \mlabel
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \johnchris_mlabel:nn { oo }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\getfromaddress{addressa.tex}
\gettoaddress{addressb.tex}

\SetEnvelope[2.0in]{240mm}{145mm}
\setlength{\EnvelopeTopMargin}{0.75in} % 0.5
\setlength{\EnvelopeLeftMargin}{1.25in} % 2.0

\begin{document}
\startlabels
\MLABEL
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly for the insightful remarks; I do find the latter example appealing.  I will have to look further into the expl3 code, as I don't understand this section.